# Xamarin, File Not Found when connected to Mac from VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

My IOS project compiles fine not connected to the Mac. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin 4.6 for VS 2017. When connected, the compiler complains about missing files under the

/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/xxx.xxx.iOS/a7656b4cad980876987183089ac940c/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-76.png

The png file (Icon-76.png) and a number of other png files are listed in the csproj file. The /Users folder does not contain the files, they reside only on my windows PC in the VS IDE.

My questions is really what is going on here. Why is the /Users folder on the Mac involved in compilation when connected.

Is there a synchronization of the assets taking place somewhere when connected to the Mac that I have missed?